# puma for heroku get error on local

Tags: heroku, puma

My rails 5 worked both in local and heroku. But for performance I follow 
heroku [doc](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server) and it work great (in heroku) but my local server on Mac Book (2015) with OS 10.12.1 has connection error the web not start with log error at connection in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debug each line add to setup Puma before push to heroku. I found this line that need to be removed from config/puma.rg

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 1)
```

causing the problem. which didn't aware because the doc from heroku only mention

```
Multi process mode does not work if you are using JRuby or Windows because the JVM and Windows do not support processes. Omit this line from your config if you are using JRuby or Windows.
```

So I would assumed either Mac Book or Mac OS 10.12.1 should be included in the list to be omitted.

After removed that line. Both local and heroku get back to work just fine.